# Should I open pull requests from a branch on the official repo or my fork?

Tags: github, pull-requests

I have commit access on an open source project named Foo hosted on GitHub (there are many other committers if that is relevant).  I would like to make a change via pull request so that someone else reviews it before it gets committed to the master branch of the Foo codebase.

To make this pull request, I can either make a branch on the official Foo repository or I could fork Foo and commit to a branch on my fork.

What issues should I consider when I'm deciding whether to make my pull request on the official repo or my fork?

Answer (score 1):

I have no direct experience with it, but my expectation is that a pull request from a fork will be scrutinized more closely and rejected more easily than a pull request from a branch in the official repo.

My reasoning for this expectation is that everyone can create a fork and submit pull requests from that fork, so the reviewer will have less confidence that the author of the change really knows the project and really knows what he is doing.
For a pull request from a branch, however, the author must have gotten enough reputation among the other maintainers to have gained commit access to the official repo, so he is likely to already have shown he understands the project and wants an extra pair of eyes to look at the change because it is unusually large or involves some risk.